# How can I avoid any type in redux Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I want to avoid **"any"** type in the react-redux typescript project. I am new to typescript but I love it but I don't understand where I should use any type.

Where to use it and where not to use it?

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface InitialState {
    id: string,
    name: string
}

const initialState: InitialState[] = [
    {id: '0', name: 'Jony'},
    {id: '1', name: 'kete'}
];


const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'users',
    initialState,
    reducers:{}
})

//Here I don't want to use any type
export const selectAllUser = (state:any) => state.users;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: You should never use `any` basically

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could change your `state:any` to
`state:InitialState[]`

Comment: Er... no, then `state.users` would give an error.

Comment: How to fixed state.user error?

Comment: You would return ```state``` instead of ```state.users```. It might make more sense to change your naming a little ```(state:any) => state.users;``` to ```(users: InitialState[]) => users;```

Answer (score 0):

type for the store

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof createStore>['getState']>;



const createStore = () => configureStore({
    reducer: {
      user: userReducer,
    },
  });
```